# For each row in one array: is it in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can check for each row in a numpy array if it can be found in another array? So if I have

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2.6], [3, 4], [2.6, 1]])
b = np.array([[0, 0], [3, 4], [1, 2.6], [4.3, 4], [5, 5]])
```

I would like to get

```
array([True, True, False])
```

Obvioulsly

```
np.isin(a,b)
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
```

is not an answer and of course I can write something like

```
return_ = np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=bool)
for index, loc in enumerate(a):
    for loc2 in b:
        if np.allclose(loc, loc2):
            return_[index] = True
            break
```

but this is slow and looks horrible. I would prefer using proper numpy commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try creating a boolean index with appropriate broadcasting and then checking in the result for a `True` subarray

```
np.any(np.all(b == a[:, None, :], axis=-1), axis=1)
```

Comment: Using `np.argwhere` instead of `np.any` allows for getting the indices and using `np.isclose` instead of `==` deals with floating point issues. Perfect!