# Numpy array, select rows while appending zeros to non-selected rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have `labels`, where it's shape is `[lb,sz]`, for example here `[3,2]`.

We have also `targets`, where it is a 1d array (size `[bz]`), use to select the `labels`.

How to select the `labels` based on `targets`, creating a new array such that its shape is `[bz,lb,sz]`, such that all except the `targets` are zeros. Look at the code snippet for example.

### Example for clarity on the problem

```py
labels = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])
print("labels", labels.shape) # labels (3, 2)

targets = np.array([0,1,1,0,2])
print("targets", targets.shape) # targets (5,)

target_labels = labels[targets]
print(target_labels)
# [[1 1]
#  [2 2]
#  [2 2]
#  [1 1]
#  [3 3]]

# TODO: need help here!
try_target_labels = np.zeros((targets.shape[0],labels.shape[0],labels.shape[1]))
try_target_labels[:,0,:] = target_labels # TODO: how to replace `0` to select based on `targets`?
print(try_target_labels)
# [[[1. 1.]
#   [0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]

#  [[2. 2.]
#   [0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]

#  [[2. 2.]
#   [0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]

#  [[1. 1.]
#   [0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]

#  [[3. 3.]
#   [0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]]

# ideal outcome
ideal_target_labels = np.array([[[1,1],[0,0],[0,0]], [[0,0],[2,2],[0,0]], [[0,0],[2,2],[0,0]], [[1,1],[0,0],[0,0]], [[0,0],[0,0],[3,3]]])
print("ideal_target_labels", ideal_target_labels.shape) # ideal_target_labels (5, 3, 2)
print(ideal_target_labels)
# [[[1 1]
#   [0 0]
#   [0 0]]

#  [[0 0]
#   [2 2]
#   [0 0]]

#  [[0 0]
#   [2 2]
#   [0 0]]

#  [[1 1]
#   [0 0]
#   [0 0]]

#  [[0 0]
#   [0 0]
#   [3 3]]]
```

p.s. I hope that the code snippet is clear, any help to rephrase the title or the questions are welcome too.

### Edit: partial correct implementation achieved, but problem when rows shared the same value

Thanks to @gofvonx contribution, `np.where(target_labels[:, None, :]==labels[None, :, :], target_labels[:, None, :], 0)` was able to get the right solution based on the example above. But the actual data, do occasionally share a few values that are the same. Look at the code snippet for example.

```py
labels = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]])
print("labels", labels.shape) # labels (3, 2)

targets = np.array([0,1,1,0,2])
print("targets", targets.shape) # targets (5,)

target_labels = labels[targets]
print("target_labels", target_labels)
# [[1 2]
#  [1 3]
#  [1 3]
#  [1 2]
#  [1 4]]

# TODO: need help here!
try_target_labels = np.zeros((targets.shape[0],labels.shape[0],labels.shape[1]))
try_target_labels = np.where(target_labels[:, None, :]==labels[None, :, :], target_labels[:, None, :], 0) # TODO: need help here!
print(try_target_labels)
# [[[1 2]
#   [1 0]
#   [1 0]]

#  [[1 0]
#   [1 3]
#   [1 0]]

#  [[1 0]
#   [1 3]
#   [1 0]]

#  [[1 2]
#   [1 0]
#   [1 0]]

#  [[1 0]
#   [1 0]
#   [1 4]]]

# ideal outcome
ideal_target_labels = np.array([[[1,2],[0,0],[0,0]], [[0,0],[1,3],[0,0]], [[0,0],[1,3],[0,0]], [[1,2],[0,0],[0,0]], [[0,0],[0,0],[1,4]]])
print("ideal_target_labels", ideal_target_labels.shape) # ideal_target_labels (5, 3, 2)
print(ideal_target_labels)
# [[[1 2]
#   [0 0]
#   [0 0]]

#  [[0 0]
#   [1 3]
#   [0 0]]

#  [[0 0]
#   [1 3]
#   [0 0]]

#  [[1 2]
#   [0 0]
#   [0 0]]

#  [[0 0]
#   [0 0]
#   [1 4]]]
```

Comment: Consider making a `np.zeros((4,3,2),int)` and copying the `target_labels` rows to the correct slots.

Comment: i tried `# try_target_labels = np.zeros((5,3,2)) # try_target_labels[:,targets] = target_labels` and other permutations. I think something like, `try_target_labels[:,0] = target_labels`, but i need a way to replace that `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do a boolean comparison with appropriate broadcasting between `target_labels` and `labels`. This yields a boolean index for filling either `target_labels` or `0` using `np.where`:

```
np.where(np.all(target_labels[:, None, :]==labels[None, :, :], axis=-1)[:, :, None], target_labels[:, None, :], 0)
```

Comment: Hi @gofvonx, I'm very thankful for your answer, I realized that there is an issue when `labels` has similar values. Look at my updated question, let me know if there is anything that's unclear, appreciate all the help that I can get.

Comment: @Jingles Good point! I have updated my answer. It now includes a check that the full sub-array is identical using `np.all` along the last axis. It is similar to my answer posted here regarding checking for the existence of sub-arrays in another array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672342/for-each-row-in-one-array-is-it-in-another-array/66672581#66672581